# Inequality with condition $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$. Prove that $$\frac{a^5}{b^3+c}+\frac{b^5}{c^3+a}+\frac{c^5}{a^3+c} \geq  \frac{3a^2b^2c^2}{2}.$$
I have tried Cauchy-Schwarz inequality in Engel/Titu Andreescu form ([see this link](https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/)), but in any attempt I cannot appropriately use the condition of the problem. Then I tried to homogenize the inequality by using the condition $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$ planning to then finalize with, for example, Muirhead's inequality - also unsuccessfully.

Comment: what have u done??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By C-S,  Vasc's inequality and AM-GM  we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^5}{b^3+c}\geq\frac{(a^3+b^3+c^3)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(b^3a+ac)}\geq\frac{(a^3+b^3+c^3)^2}{3+3}\geq\frac{9a^2b^2c^2}{6}=\frac{3a^2b^2c^2}{2}.$$
The Vasc's inequality is the following:
$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\geq3(b^3a+c^3b+a^3c).$$
Also I used $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+ac+bc.$

Comment: Link to numerous proofs of this Vasc(=[Vasile Cirtoaje](https://cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/VasileCirtoaje.pdf))'s inequality: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h536442p3080843